# Wix - How to kill any process forcefully through custom action?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, custom-action

I have a created msi and installed it but i am facing an issue during uninstall. I want to close the application forcefully before uninstall through custom action - wix
I've searched a lot but didn't find any solution.
I want a solution something like that.

```
<Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value='"[SystemFolder]taskkill.exe" /F /IM ConfigurationManager.exe     /t'/> 
<CustomAction Id="StopUserExe" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate"     Return="ignore"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='StopUserExe' Before='RemoveFiles'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the above solution?

Comment: It does not exit my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [Taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)?

Example:

```
<CustomAction Id="TaskKill" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="taskkill /f /im notepad.exe" />
```

Comment: i have tried this. When i manually execute taskkill commantd it give "Access Denied" error. But when i run cmd.exe as administrator then the command execute successfuly. I don't know how to give administrative privileges in CstomAction command.

Comment: The .msi packages should automatically ask for elevation at some point.

Note the 'Execute' enumeration in [CustomAction element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)

Also note the [InstallExecuteSequence element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/installexecutesequence.html).

You have to execute the after the installer has elevated
e.g.

`<InstallExecuteSequence> <Custom Action="TaskKill" After="InstallInitialize">1</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>`

Comment: Its working. I was trying to solve this since yesterday. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm doing the same and it's not working with me
is there any other way?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore from what I can see. I also get an error when the MSI tries to run this.

Answer (score -1):

In your custom action you can enumerate processes (EnumProcesses()) and call TerminateProcess() for the needed one.